# Dart how to pass generic function to isolate

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is there a way to pass a generic Function as Parameter to an Isolate at spawn? I have attached a simplifyed version of my code (not working) but is there a way to archive this without dynamics? Or is the Type of the functionToCall decided at runtime and not at complietime and so not possible to decide for an isolate?

```
import 'dart:isolate';

class TestClass {
  // ...
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

  Isolate.spawn(functionToCall<TestClass>, receivePort.sendPort);
}

void functionToCall<T>(SendPort sendPort) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything about a generic type is known as part of the compilation, and "reified" for the same information to be double-checked at Runtime.

Comment: Okay thats good :) but how can i than pass a generic function to the Isolate.spawn method? I come from C++ where it is no problem with templates and using it as i have shown in my example.

Comment: You probably need just one API per Isolate.  If you have more APIs, spawn more Isolates. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here maybe not so much with Isolates, but that I don't know of any way in Dart that you can have create a function reference to a generic function.

eg, you can call certainly call your generic function:

```
functionToCall<TestClass>(myPort);
```

But I dont see how you can create a reference to the function for a specific type (TestClass) and its a function reference that you need too pass into the spawn method, so I think thats the limitation in Dart that you are running into here.

Answer (score 0):

Define a generic class

```
class MyGenericClass<T> {
  T value;

  MyGenericClass(this.value);
}
```

Call the function in Isolate.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Create an instance of MyGenericClass
  MyGenericClass<int> myInstance = MyGenericClass(5);

  // Spawn the isolate and pass the MyGenericClass instance
  final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(isolateFunction, receivePort.sendPort);

  // Send the MyGenericClass instance to the isolate
  final SendPort sendPort = await receivePort.first;
  sendPort.send(myInstance);

  // Receive the processed data from the isolate
  receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
    if (data is MyGenericClass) {
      // Handle the processed data in the main isolate
      print('Processed value: ${data.value}');

      // Close the receive port to terminate the isolate
      receivePort.close();
    }
  });
}
```

Function to be executed in the isolate

```
void isolateFunction(SendPort sendPort) {
  // Receive the MyGenericClass instance from the main isolate
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

  receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
    // Perform any processing on the generic class
    if (data is MyGenericClass) {
      // Process the data in the isolate
      data.value = data.value * 2;

      // Send the processed data back to the main isolate
      sendPort.send(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this part of Dart 3, as there the constraints of data passed to an isolate got loosened?